# Encode and decode skipping the characters

Tags: javascript, html, base64, decode, encode

I am trying to store some strings into the database using their encoded format. But when retrieving back the string is malformed.

Here is my code example where you easily can see that String passed to encode is not the same as after decode. Why is this happening?

Is there any other library which can help me encoding and decoding? Any suggestion on the same will be helpful.

```js
var Base64 = {
    _keyStr : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",
    encode : function(e) {
        var t = "";
        var n, r, i, s, o, u, a;
        var f = 0;
        e = Base64._utf8_encode(e);
        while (f < e.length) {
            n = e.charCodeAt(f++);
            r = e.charCodeAt(f++);
            i = e.charCodeAt(f++);
            s = n >> 2;
            o = (n & 3) << 4 | r >> 4;
            u = (r & 15) << 2 | i >> 6;
            a = i & 63;
            if (isNaN(r)) {
                u = a = 64
            } else if (isNaN(i)) {
                a = 64
            }
            t = t + this._keyStr.charAt(s) + this._keyStr.charAt(o)
                    + this._keyStr.charAt(u) + this._keyStr.charAt(a)
        }
        return t
    },
    decode : function(e) {
        var t = "";
        var n, r, i;
        var s, o, u, a;
        var f = 0;
        e = e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]/g, "");
        while (f < e.length) {
            s = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
            o = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
            u = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
            a = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
            n = s << 2 | o >> 4;
            r = (o & 15) << 4 | u >> 2;
            i = (u & 3) << 6 | a;
            t = t + String.fromCharCode(n);
            if (u != 64) {
                t = t + String.fromCharCode(r)
            }
            if (a != 64) {
                t = t + String.fromCharCode(i)
            }
        }
        t = Base64._utf8_decode(t);
        return t
    },
    _utf8_encode : function(e) {
        e = e.replace(/rn/g, "n");
        var t = "";
        for (var n = 0; n < e.length; n++) {
            var r = e.charCodeAt(n);
            if (r < 128) {
                t += String.fromCharCode(r)
            } else if (r > 127 && r < 2048) {
                t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 6 | 192);
                t += String.fromCharCode(r & 63 | 128)
            } else {
                t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 12 | 224);
                t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 6 & 63 | 128);
                t += String.fromCharCode(r & 63 | 128)
            }
        }
        return t
    },
    _utf8_decode : function(e) {
        var t = "";
        var n = 0;
        var r = c1 = c2 = 0;
        while (n < e.length) {
            r = e.charCodeAt(n);
            if (r < 128) {
                t += String.fromCharCode(r);
                n++
            } else if (r > 191 && r < 224) {
                c2 = e.charCodeAt(n + 1);
                t += String.fromCharCode((r & 31) << 6 | c2 & 63);
                n += 2
            } else {
                c2 = e.charCodeAt(n + 1);
                c3 = e.charCodeAt(n + 2);
                t += String.fromCharCode((r & 15) << 12 | (c2 & 63) << 6 | c3
                        & 63);
                n += 3
            }
        }
        return t
    }
}


var str = "background:url(/XYX/player_assets/skin_0/XYXA_default_skinRightCorner.png) ;"

var encoded = Base64.encode(str);
//console.log(encoded);

var decoded = Base64.decode(encoded);
console.log(str,"......Input");
console.log(decoded,".....Output");
```

Comment: You don't need your own Base64 functions. You can use the built in `atob` and `btoa` instead.

Comment: Can you provide me a working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Base64 Encoding in common browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding)

> In JavaScript there are two functions respectively for decoding and encoding base64 strings:
>
> `atob()`
>
> `btoa()`
>
> The `atob()` function decodes a string of data which has been encoded using base-64 encoding. Conversely, the `btoa()` function creates a base-64 encoded ASCII string from a "string" of binary data.

Answer (score 1):

Use `atob` and `btoa`.

```js
const foo = "bar"

const encodedFoo = btoa(foo)
const decodedFoo = atob(encodedFoo)

console.log(encodedFoo)
console.log(decodedFoo)
```

You can read more about it [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding)

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but if you can explain the logic behind given methods by you. And what was the problem in my code then I will accept this answer

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to explain, these functions are built into JavaScript. As for your code, I don't know, it's usually not trivial for any dev to understand code that uses one letter variable names.

Comment: I truly understand, thanks a ton for the response. It made my day.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong here (_utf8_encode):
`e = e.replace(/rn/g, "n");`
Correct like this:
`e = e.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");`

```js
var Base64 = {
    _keyStr : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",
    encode : function(e) {
        var t = "";
        var n, r, i, s, o, u, a;
        var f = 0;
        e = Base64._utf8_encode(e);
        while (f < e.length) {
            n = e.charCodeAt(f++);
            r = e.charCodeAt(f++);
            i = e.charCodeAt(f++);
            s = n >> 2;
            o = (n & 3) << 4 | r >> 4;
            u = (r & 15) << 2 | i >> 6;
            a = i & 63;
            if (isNaN(r)) {
                u = a = 64
            } else if (isNaN(i)) {
                a = 64
            }
            t = t + this._keyStr.charAt(s) + this._keyStr.charAt(o)
                    + this._keyStr.charAt(u) + this._keyStr.charAt(a)
        }
        return t
    },
    decode : function(e) {
        var t = "";
        var n, r, i;
        var s, o, u, a;
        var f = 0;
        e = e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]/g, "");
        while (f < e.length) {
            s = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
            o = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
            u = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
            a = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
            n = s << 2 | o >> 4;
            r = (o & 15) << 4 | u >> 2;
            i = (u & 3) << 6 | a;
            t = t + String.fromCharCode(n);
            if (u != 64) {
                t = t + String.fromCharCode(r)
            }
            if (a != 64) {
                t = t + String.fromCharCode(i)
            }
        }
        t = Base64._utf8_decode(t);
        return t
    },
    _utf8_encode : function(e) {
        e = e.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
        var t = "";
        for (var n = 0; n < e.length; n++) {
            var r = e.charCodeAt(n);
            if (r < 128) {
                t += String.fromCharCode(r)
            } else if (r > 127 && r < 2048) {
                t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 6 | 192);
                t += String.fromCharCode(r & 63 | 128)
            } else {
                t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 12 | 224);
                t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 6 & 63 | 128);
                t += String.fromCharCode(r & 63 | 128)
            }
        }
        return t
    },
    _utf8_decode : function(e) {
        var t = "";
        var n = 0;
        var r = c1 = c2 = 0;
        while (n < e.length) {
            r = e.charCodeAt(n);
            if (r < 128) {
                t += String.fromCharCode(r);
                n++
            } else if (r > 191 && r < 224) {
                c2 = e.charCodeAt(n + 1);
                t += String.fromCharCode((r & 31) << 6 | c2 & 63);
                n += 2
            } else {
                c2 = e.charCodeAt(n + 1);
                c3 = e.charCodeAt(n + 2);
                t += String.fromCharCode((r & 15) << 12 | (c2 & 63) << 6 | c3
                        & 63);
                n += 3
            }
        }
        return t
    }
}


var str = "background:url(/xyx-courses/player_assets/skin_0/XYX_default_skinRightCorner.png) ;"

var encoded = Base64.encode(str);
//console.log(encoded);

var decoded = Base64.decode(encoded);
console.log(str,"......Input");
console.log(decoded,".....Output");
```

Also, I think this line `e = e.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");` is not needed here at all, because the task is to encode the string as utf8 into base64, and not convert additional `CRLF` to `LF` (line break)